# How to use Solr's indexes files

Tags: solr, sunspot

I am writing an customize algorithm upon a Ruby on Rails application which uses Solr & Sunspot for full text search. I want to make use of the index files that Solr generated, especially the TF*IDF value of the indexed words. Is there an easy way to access to these index information?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Solr Function queries for [tf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery/#tf), [idf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery/#tf) ?  If you are using a later version of Solr you can sort by a function query response.